# Product Bar code Search API

Tags: android, iphone, search, google-search

I am using Google Product Search API in one of my application but as it is deprecated now. Please suggest What is the best alternative for Google Product search API.

Answer (score 0):

I got these two solutions from [Search API for Shopping is Deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-search-api-for-shopping/UhpKmDe56WM) on Google Group.

- https://www.semantics3.com/
- http://www.wisepricer.com/wisematch